# Deep-linking not working on Android 13 with React Native

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, android-deep-link, android-13, android-13-deeplink

I have some links that should redirect to specific pages in my app; I followed the instructions on https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/deep-linking/ and it works fine on previous Android versions, but on version 13, they all redirect to the Home page.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
          <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" tools:targetApi="m">
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
              <data
                  android:scheme="https"
                  android:host="campanha.soustix.com.br"/>
          </intent-filter>
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="br.com.soustix.NOTIFICATIONPRESSED" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          </intent-filter>
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

deepLinkRoutes.rs:

```
export const linkingConfig = {
  config: {
    screens: {
      Home: {
        screens: {
          HomePage: 'app',
          MyExchanges: 'vouchers',
          Explore: 'explore'
        }
      },
      ProductDetail: 'product/:id',
      P2PPresentation: 'p2p',
      MGM: 'invitefriends',
      Extract: 'extract',
      MyAccount: 'myaccount',
      JoinStix: 'joinstix',
      Login: 'iam',
      Catalog: 'catalog',
      PartnerDetail: 'iupp',
      Search: 'categories/:rootCategory'
    }
  }
};
```

App.tsx:

```
import { linkingConfig } from './src/config/deepLinkRoutes';
//rest of the code
<NavigationContainer linking={{ prefixes: ['
https://campanha.soustix.com.br/redirect'] }} >
```

I tried to run `adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://campanha.soustix.com.br/redirect/p2p" br.com.soustixp` but I just get `error: activity not started, unable to resolve intent { act=android.intent.action.view dat=https://campanhasoustix.com.br/... flg=0x10000000 pkg=br.com.soustix }`
Also tried adding android:pathPrefix="/redirect/p2p" to the data tag but that didn't work either. Please, what am I missing?

Comment: Instead of URL, try to use `schema` and then try it again. If schema works then seek to find why the URL doesn't work

Comment: @AmerllicA could you please give me more details on how to try that? Thank you

Comment: Like [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/#linking) explains, use a schema for your `prefixes`, eg: `prefixes: ['joaoraffo://'],`. Then for testing the deep link in the browser address bar type: `joaoraffo://some-page-name`. it should open your app, or ask you to open it. if it works, then try to add a web address prefix, if it works try the above address. step by step fix your problem.

Comment: And by this line: `<NavigationContainer linking={{ prefixes: ['
https://campanha.soustix.com.br/redirect'] }} >` I guess you haven't understood the deep linking pretty well. you should use schema and a simple website name. then the App will be opened by schema or a link that contains that prefixes address. Inside the app you can catch up the rest of address and try to use it.

Comment: @AmerllicA thank you so much. It's still not working on the browser, but it works when I run adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://campanha.soustix.com.br/redirect/extract" br.com.soustix.app

Comment: Leave the browser, I said browser for schema, not the web link. Definitely, a browser should open the web. So that's ok. Which of my comments helped you? I want to post it as answer.

Comment: The second one.

Answer (score 0):

The way of linking definitions and way of using them isn't correct. Based on [react navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/#linking) you can define like the following for example:

```js
<NavigationContainer
  linking={{ prefixes: ['joaoraffo://'] }}
>
  ~~~
</NavigationContainer>
```

Then the App will be opened by schema or a link that contains that prefix address. Inside the app, you can catch up with the rest of the addresses and try to use it